# Convert html entities to ascii in Python

Tags: python, ascii

I need to convert any html entity into its ASCII equivalent using Python. My use case is that I am cleaning up some HTML used to build emails to create plaintext emails from the HTML.

Right now, I only really know how to create unicode from these entities when I need ASCII (I think) so that the plaintext email reads correctly with things like accented characters. I think a basic example is the html entity "& aacute;" or á being encoded into ASCII.

Furthermore, I'm not even 100% sure that ASCII is what I need for a plaintext email. As you can tell, I'm completely lost on this encoding stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII is the American Standard Code for Information Interchange and does **not** include any accented letters. Your best bet is to get Unicode (as you say you can) and encode it as UTF-8 (maybe ISO-8859-1 or some weird codepage if you're dealing with seriously badly coded user-agents/clients, sigh) -- the content type header of that part together with text/plain can express what encoding you've chosen to use (I do recommend trying UTF-8 unless you have positively demonstrated it cannot work -- it's *almost* universally supported these days and MUCH more flexible than any ISO-8859 or "codepage" hack!).

Comment: This worked well moving stuff to unicode first and then on to UTF-8, at least in my preliminary tests. We'll have to send out some mail tomorrow and see how it plays in the email clients. Thanks for the detailed explanation as to what I might really want as well.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a complete implementation that also handles unicode html entities. You might find it useful.

It returns a unicode string that is not ascii, but if you want plain ascii, you can modify the replace operations so that it replaces the entities to empty string.

```
def convert_html_entities(s):
    matches = re.findall("&#\d+;", s)
    if len(matches) > 0:
        hits = set(matches)
        for hit in hits:
            name = hit[2:-1]
            try:
                entnum = int(name)
                s = s.replace(hit, unichr(entnum))
            except ValueError:
                pass

    matches = re.findall("&#[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+;", s)
    if len(matches) > 0:
        hits = set(matches)
        for hit in hits:
            hex = hit[3:-1]
            try:
                entnum = int(hex, 16)
                s = s.replace(hit, unichr(entnum))
            except ValueError:
                pass

    matches = re.findall("&\w+;", s)
    hits = set(matches)
    amp = "&amp;"
    if amp in hits:
        hits.remove(amp)
    for hit in hits:
        name = hit[1:-1]
        if htmlentitydefs.name2codepoint.has_key(name):
            s = s.replace(hit, unichr(htmlentitydefs.name2codepoint[name]))
    s = s.replace(amp, "&")
    return s
```

Edit: added matching for hexcodes. I've been using this for a while now, and ran into my first situation with ' which is a single quote/apostrophe.

Comment: Nice answer. It seems there should be something in a standard module to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [htmlentitydefs](http://docs.python.org/library/htmllib.html#module-htmlentitydefs) package:

```
import htmlentitydefs
print htmlentitydefs.entitydefs['aacute']
```

Basically, `entitydefs` is just a dictionary, and you can see this by printing it at the python prompt:

```
from pprint import pprint 
pprint htmlentitydefs.entitydefs
```

Comment: that gives you (roughly) ISO-8859-1 codes -- which these days is a hopelessly obsolete approach even for a stubborn "western/european supremacist" (for example, even the _euro sign_ doesn't fit there...!!!).  htmlentitydefs.name2codepoint, which uniformly gives you the numeric codepoint (which you can turn into a unicode string of length 1 with unichr -- and then .encode as you wish), is vastly preferable.

Comment: Thanks for input ars. It certainly seems to get me the ASCII-ish stuff that I asked for, but I also needed a little more guidance on my use case as well.

Comment: @aezell: Sure thing. I prefer Alex's answer, too, for the big picture, as well as his specific suggestions to my own answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

We put up a little module with agazso's function:

http://github.com/ARTFL/util/blob/master/ents.py

We find agazso's function to faster than the alternatives for ent conversion. Thanks for posting it.